# Why the image in RMarkdown is in scroll view and doesn't display properly?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use the following in my RMarkdown file, and the output HTML shows the images in a scroll view and also doesn't display properly.

````
---
title: "XXX"
author: "me"
date: "date"
output:
  html_document: default
keep_md: true
---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                          fig.path = "Plots/",
                          dev = c("png", "pdf"),
                          fig.width = 10,
                          fig.height = 7,
                          dpi = 300)
    ```

Some text

Code 

Code

Code

```{r myplot, dev="pdf", fig.width=7, fig.height=7}
ggplot......
```
````

So, with the above, in the folder `Plots` I have the `myplot.pdf` but in the HTML file it showed like below:

[image]

I need to scroll to view the whole image, and don't get what is that black stuff.

Comment: What's in the PDF when you open it outside of RMD? Can you share an image of the file? When you have to scroll, is there a large black (or any color) blank area to the right of the plot? I don't know if this is the problem, but `html_document` has a present `max-width`. If I leave the settings as is, I end of with more margin than content. If this is the issue, you can add this outside of an R chunk: `<style>.main-container {   max-width: unset; }</style>` (`main-container` is the class, if that prepended period gets lost in this comment.)

Comment: The pdf which I open outside looks completely fine. But the problem is with the only images in the HTML file. It looks like above in HTML.

Comment: this is also happening for me- did you find a solution @beginner ?